# Not able to access SPSite object, throwing exception

Tags: sharepoint-2010

```
   try
        {
         string targetSite = "https://abc.xyz.com/"; 
             using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(targetSite))
             {
               lblStatus.Text = "SharePoint Connection - Success";                    
             }
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           lblStatus.Text = "SharePoint Connection - Success";
        }
```

Trying to run above code in visual studio 2012 in console application then it is running fine but if I try to run same in web application project then it is throwing below exception. I am trying this code on server where SharePoint 2010 is installed and using .NET 3.5 Any clue why this is happening!!

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "The Web application at http://abc.xyz.com could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application."

Answer (score 0):

Here are the most common reasons this error can occur:

**The code is executed on a different machine** - The SharePoint object model (except the Client API) requires to be run on the SharePoint server itself. It is not possible to run the application on a server which is not within the same SharePoint farm the code is trying to access.

**Insufficient Rights on the site collection** - The code is executed in context of an account which does not have read permission on the site collection
Incorrect Url being used - Verify that the site works correct in a browser and double check that the server is correct registered in the AAM settings

**Incorrect bitness** - The SharePoint object model needs to be executed with the same bitness as the operating system. That means you cannot use the SharePoint object model in a 32-bit application if the Operating System and SharePoint are installed as 64-bit version. Ensure to compile the project using the correct bitness (64-bit on a 64-bit machine vs. 32-bit on a 32-bit machine)

**Incorrect .NET framework version** -  Ensure that the project is configured to use .NET 3.5 for SharePoint 2010 and below and .NET 4.0 for SharePoint 2013

[Source](http://asharepointsolutions.blogspot.in/2013/07/microsoft-sharepoint-is-not-supported.html)

Also Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable.
[image]

Comment: Hi I found that If I run this above code in console application then it is running fine but if I am running same code in web application then it is throwing this exception. I am running this code on server where SharePoint 2010 is installed and using .NET 3.5
Any clue!!